# For data that follows an exponential trend, is there a single equation to relate standard deviation, mean, and sample size?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, standard-deviation, sample-size, exponential-distribution

Essentially, is there an equation that consists of mean, sample size, and standard deviation (or standard error of the mean) whereby I could know two of the three values and calculate the third parameter? For example, if I had the mean spacing between events and the total number of events, could I calculate the standard deviation?

Comment: One way to see that this is impossible is to find two possible samples which have the same mean and sample size but different standard deviations.

Comment: @fblundun is there some underlying 4th variable that could make this possible?